# Reference specific model item in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently trying to attempt something in Ember.js and I'm really not sure how to do it.

I want to reference model items twice in the same view. On the left hand side, I have a iterated list of items; that easy enough.  But in the middle of the page, I want to create a grid with a specific layout (probably hard coded, not iterated) of those same items. Eventually, along the left, each item will have its own input to set it's value and I want to display that set value in the grid in the center.

I've tried doing this in a couple of different ways, by creating a special view, using renders and valueBindings, but none of it has worked quite right.  I'm new to Ember.js so I'd appreciate any help.  You can view a jsBin of here (http://jsbin.com/inapoh/1/edit).  Also, would the approach be different if I wanted to also provide an input in the grid and sync that back to the list?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `{{each}}` helper for both, the list and the grid, this will make it a lot easier to manage the associations between the input field value and the value shown in the grid, however this depends on your use case.

See this modification of your code how this could look like: http://jsbin.com/inapoh/4/edit

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

first of, where you are rendering the TextField:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="newValue" action="setValue"}}
```

you would need to do this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="value"}}
```

that way, Ember will render the value of the 'value' property of each of your items, and it will also update that property of your model every time you change it on the screen. With that said, you would need to loop again through your items, to display them in the middle of the screen, instead of hard coded, and you can also access to the 'value' property of each of your items there, that way it will be automatically updated after you change it in the left side.